# fatal error: 'upb/msg.h' file not found (apple m1 chip)

Tags: ios, flutter

I am getting this error : "fatal error: 'upb/msg.h' file not found" every time I am trying to lunch my flutter app on VScode on iphone 11
this is my dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

someone know how do I fix it ?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? How are you launching the app (VSCode, XCode, ...) what device are you running it on ...

Comment: I am lunching the app on vs code on iphone 11

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be of pod cache and you might need to delete it then install it with `pod install` check this [source](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3133) and that also if didnt worked then try deleting your `generated_plugin_registrant` file and run `flutter clean` and then `flutter create .`